# How to run multiple class files of java via batch file

Tags: java, maven, batch-file, cucumber, cucumber-java

I have a selenium maven project that uses Cucumber framework. I run my maven suite first and then I have a separate java class (having main()) within the same project repository. I want to run my maven tests first followed by this java class from a batch file. This java class should run only if my maven tests are run successfully and closes the browser and all (in @After as usual). I tried something like below but only my maven tests run but the java class isn't picked up. Any help, please?

```
set projectpath=C:\Users\myProjectPath

cd %projectpath%

mvn install -Dcucumber.options="--tags @myTag"

javac ThisIsTheClassIWantToRunAfterCucumber.java

java ThisIsTheClassIWantToRunAfterCucumber

pause
```

Comment: 1. mvn is a bat file and you need to execute it with `call mvn...`  2. why you dont compile your classes with maven?  3. If the classes are in a package it should be included in the command.

Comment: Is it like this, @npocmaka?  set projectpath=C:\Users\myProjectPath
cd %projectpath%
mvn install -Dcucumber.options="--tags @myTag"
cd myPackagePath
mvn test-compile testMainPackage.MyClass
pause

Comment: you still need to use `call mvn install -..` . you dont need to enter the package path. just use `java com.package.something.MyClass` both with `javac` and `java` commands.

Comment: @npocmaka I gave something like this and still doesn't work... Can you help me with the correct command as I'm new to this?: set projectpath=C:\Users\myProjectPath
cd %projectpath%
mvn install -Dcucumber.options="--tags @myTag"
mvn install -Dtest=ClassName test
javac testMainPackage.ClassName
java testMainPackage.ClassName
pause

Comment: In a console window, try `help call`.

Comment: Nothing is helping me :(

Comment: I fixed this myself with the help of @npocmaka comment.

Answer (score 0):

We have to call the "call" command before the mvn command and tried pointing to my project again.

```
set projectpath=projectPath
cd %projectpath%
call mvn install -Dcucumber.options="--tags @myTag"
echo on
cd %projectpath%
call mvn exec:java
echo on
pause
```